# Java applet with external jar cannot display whole apple application

Tags: java, applet, antlr, japplet

I use ANTLR make a small java applet. I can run it from eclipse without any problem, but once i put it on the web-page. Applet cannot display any stuff.
such as button never is displayed until I use mouse over it.

```
    <applet 
     code="gui.FGG_main" 
     width="790" 
     height="545"
     archive="fgg.jar,antlrworks-1.4.3.jar,output.jar">
    </applet>
```

Can any people help, and tell me what happened

Comment: *"Can any people help?"*  <DWS>Change column 37, line 142 of the source from a .` to a `,` and everything will be fine.</DWS>  Failing that, post 1) An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) The [console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) output. 3) The URL where we can see the applet fail.  -- Why are you coding an applet rather than a desktop app.?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use deployJava.js. 
You can find it in [this Oracle tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html)
The tutorial describes in detail every step neccessary.

Comment: I try the jnlp, but have the same problem.

Comment: Do you use custom images for the buttons? From your explanation its possible that Applet doesn't have the images. This could explain why the Applet works in Eclipse, but not in the web browser (You might image-url might be local or don't refer to the exported resources correctly). Do you use the Java-Console for debugging? This way you might see wether or not your Applet has any errors. You can learn how to activate it here: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml